# How to draw an ellipse C# via GDI?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing

I am new in C# and i am trying to draw a color filled ellipse, I foud some code but i couldn't figure out how to do it.

I tried with this code:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Aquamarine, 2);
g.DrawEllipse(pen, 10, 10, 100, 20);
```

But the method does not exist.

Colud you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which method doesn't exist? DrawEllipse?

Comment: Me neither, because this method exists: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt06kxfd.aspx What error message are you getting?

Comment: Did you include system.drawing?

Comment: Is `Graphics` really denoting `System.Drawing.Graphics` rather than some other type with the same name?

Answer (score 2):

You should do your graphics drawing in the forms Paint Event, otherwise as soon as the screen updates you will loose your drawing. This is a quick and dirty example on how to do so.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
}

void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Aquamarine,2);
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Aquamarine);

    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, 10, 10, 100, 20);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, 10, 50, 100, 20);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really deal with the `DrawEllipse` method allegedly not being found.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes it does be cause it is part of the PaintEventHandler, I am not sure why he can't access it the way he is trying, but I know he can access it this way. And he will have problems with his image being retained if he doesn't use the PaintEvent to draw them.

Comment: Being part of the `PaintEventHandler` doesn't change anything about the visibility of `DrawEllipse` - that method should be invokeable just as much as it should be in the original code. Obviously, some information is missing in the question; let's see whether the OP supplies any additional info.